# How -d checks directory exists?

Tags: linux, bash

I made a simple bash scripts where his first argument take a path and check if is a directory or not.

```
if [ -d $1 ]
then
    echo $1 is a directory
else
    echo $1 is not a directory
fi
```

My problem is when I run the script whitout any arguments and the script return true

Answer (score 1):

You didn't quote `$1`, so if the expansion produces an empty string, the test devolves to `[ -d ]`, in which case `-d` is *not* treated as a file system test, but simply as a non-empty string, equivalent to `[ -n -d ]`. `-d` is not an empty string, so the `[` command succeeds.

Always quote parameter expansions unless you know why *not* quoting it is required (or at least inconsequential):

```
if [ -d "$1" ]
then
    echo "$1 is a directory"
else
    echo "$1 is not a directory"
fi
```

Comment: messed up the last answer